# Pull images off a webserver to iconic android app

Tags: android, html, cordova

I developed an app in html and jquery mobile USING ICONIC, what I want to do now is pull images from a web server and display them on one of the pages in my app.
I am not sure how to go about this could anybody point in the right direction

server running
Apache ver. 2.2.19 (Unix)
PHP version 5.2.*
MySQL ver.  5.1

thanks

Comment: whats the full software specs for  your web server. i.e whats running. Put hat info in your Q

Comment: its just the free hosting provided by 000webhost the images are put onto it using ftp from a java program im running

Comment: ok, thats better.  So the best and fastest way will be to add the links to the images in an MYSQL database, and use a PHP script to access the database and table to read the links and pass then to your App. On the App side you need to use ajax (check ionic docs for that) to call the PHP script so it returns the links. Then is just a case of appending images using the (img) html tag with the image source

Comment: ok ill start looking in to that just wasnt sure where to start thanks for the help  @Tasos

Comment: The good thing about using a database is organization. Hypothetically speaking you could add a genge column and query the db to pull in all images that are flowers or buildings etc. you can add information each image, create galleries, groups, etc